# How to access a method from a class defined in .DLL file from JAVA program?

Tags: java, c++, dll, java-native-interface

I have a DLL file which has a class defined as 'Handler' which in turn contains method call getProperty(string,string).

How can I access such method from a JAVA program??

** I see a lot of examples on net which allows invocation of global function defined inside the DLL, but don't see any examples where we can invoke an method on a native object.

Comment: Have looked at JNI and JNA?  JNI is the "Java Native Interface", JNA is a wrapper around this to make it easier to access native libraries

Comment: What kind of DLL is it? Do you have the source code?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments JNI is something you are looking for, but you will not be able to use "native" class/objects on Java side.

You'll need to add "native C" bridge layer with pure `C` API, which will wrap your `C++` interface and translate calls to DLL, because only such API can be used on Java side via JNI.